# Perl forking server test program - accept() failing

Tags: perl, sockets, fork

I'm trying to put together a skeletal server (in Perl) that follows some of the guidelines I'm reading about in *Network Programming with Perl* by Lincoln Stein (c. 2001).  What I have here is a simple echo server that forks a child for each connection and echoes back whatever it receives until it receives the termination token.

I had a primitive version working, and then added new features such as a $SIG{CHLD} handler and more closing of "unnecessary" file handles after forking, and now it's broken: it terminates the while() loop after a connection finishes.  (I've tried selectively backing out changes but to no avail.)

Here are runnable versions of both the server and a client that illustrate the bug.  The problem may be evident from simply inspecting the code.  If you want to run it, you terminate the client by entering a single period (.) which is the termination token - that will trigger the bug in the server.

Server:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

# Template for a server.
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp;
use Getopt::Std;
use File::Basename;
use IO::Socket;
use Net::hostent;    # for OO version of gethostbyaddr
use POSIX 'WNOHANG';
use Data::Dumper;
use 5.010;

my $program    = basename $0;
my $master_pid = $$;            # Master server's pid
$|             = 1;             # flush STDOUT buffer regularly

###############################################################################
#
# Initialize.
#
###############################################################################

my %opts;
getopts( 'hp:', \%opts );

if ( $opts{'h'} ) {    # no args, or the -h arg
    print <<EOF;

      Usage:  $program [-p port]

      Where:  -p port      advertised port number, > 1024 (default: 2000)

EOF
    exit(0);
}

my $server_port = $opts{p} || 2000;

croak "-p port omitted.\n" if !defined $server_port;
croak "port must be numeric.\n" if $server_port !~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/;
croak "port must be 1025 .. 65535.\n"
    if $server_port < 1025 || $server_port > 65535;

# Set up a child-reaping subroutine for SIGCHLD
#
$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    while ( ( my $kid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG )) > 0 ) {
    }
};





###############################################################################
#
# Become a server.
#
###############################################################################

# Open the server's advertised port for incoming connections
#
my $listen_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Proto     => 'tcp',
    LocalPort => $server_port,
    Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
    Reuse     => 1
);
croak "Can't set up listening port: $!\n" unless $listen_socket;
say "Server ready.";

# Block on accept() call until a new connection arrives
#
my $client_fh;
while ( $client_fh = $listen_socket->accept() ) {

    $client_fh->autoflush(1);                      # turn on frequent flushing
    my $hostinfo
        = gethostbyaddr( $client_fh->peeraddr );   # resolve ipaddr to name

    # Now that a connection is established, spawn a conversation.
    #
    defined (my $child_pid = fork())
                 or croak "Can't fork: $!\n";

    if ( $child_pid == 0 ) {    # if being run by the forked child

        # S T A R T   O F   C H I L D   C O N T E X T
        #
        conversate($client_fh); # run the child process
        #
        # E N D   O F   C H I L D   C O N T E X T
    }

    $client_fh->close;     # Parent immediately closes its copy 
}

say "Bummer - for some reason the socket->accept() failed.";


###############################################################################
#
#                          S U B R O U T I N E S
#
###############################################################################

# conversate ( client_fh )
#
# S T A R T   O F   C H I L D   P R O C E S S
#
sub conversate {

    my $client_fh = shift;    # connection to client
    $listen_socket->close;    # we don't need our copy of this
    my $child_pid = $$;       # get our new pid

    print $client_fh "READY\n";    # tell them we're here

 EXCHANGE:
    while (1) {

        # Let client talk first
        #
        my $line = <$client_fh>;   # ?? Isn't there an OO way?

        if ( !defined $line ) {
            last EXCHANGE;
        }

        chomp $line;

        last EXCHANGE if $line eq '.';

        # Now send a reply (echo) and close the connection.
        #
        print $client_fh "$line\n";  # ?? Isn't there an OO way?
    }
    exit 0;                 # child process exits
}
#
# E N D   O F   C H I L D   P R O C E S S
```

Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#

use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;
use 5.010;

#sub say { print "@_\n"; }

my $program = basename $0;

my %opts;
getopts( 'hvs:p:', \%opts );

if ( $opts{'h'} ) {    # -h arg
    print <<EOF;

      Usage:  $program [-v] [-s hostname [-p port]]

      Where:
              -s hostname   host name (default: localhost)
              -p port       port number (default: 2000)
              -v            verbose mode

EOF
    exit;
}

my $verbose  = $opts{v} || 0;
my $hostname = $opts{s} || 'localhost';    # hard coded for now
my $port     = $opts{p} || 2000;

###############################################################################
#
# Initialize
#
###############################################################################

# Initialize the ReadLine terminal
#
use Term::ReadLine;
my $term = Term::ReadLine->new($0);

###############################################################################
#
# Contact server and begin main loop
#
###############################################################################

use IO::Socket;
my $remote = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Proto    => "tcp",
    PeerAddr => $hostname,
    PeerPort => $port,
) or die "Cannot connect to $hostname:$port";

my $line;
EXCHANGE:
while (1) {

    # Wait for server
    #
    $line = <$remote>;
    last EXCHANGE if !defined $line; # connection closed by remote?

    # Print server response
    #
    chomp $line;
    say "SERVER: $line";

    # Read from STDIN
    #
    $line = $term->readline("Enter something: ");

    chomp $line;

    # Send to server
    #
    print $remote "$line\n";

}

close $remote or die "Close failed: $!";

print "\n$program exiting normally.\n\n";
exit;
```

Comment: Tip of the day: use [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), and remember to commit often. That way, you _will_ be able to back out of troublesome changes, and find out exactly where things broke.

Comment: It contains "No child processes".

Comment: Add `local $!;` to your signal handler, then try again. But the fact that the signal handler is running (as indicated by this error message) is pretty good confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what error is returned? Check `$!`.

I bet `accept` is being interrupted by `SIGCHLD`. A program cannot handle signals when it has ceded control to the OS, so to give your program a chance signals, blocking system calls return (with error `EINTR`) when a signal with a handler is raised.

Once your handler has handled the signal (which happens before you even notice `accept` returning), you can simply restart the `accept`. In other words, you can address this problem by writing your loop as follows:

```
while (1) {
    my $client_fh = $listen_socket->accept();
    if (!$client_fh) {
       redo if $!{EINTR};
       last;
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that you'll have to stop your signal handler from clobbering `$!` by adding the following to it:

```
local ( $!, $^E, $@ );
```

Comment: Before I saw your note about 'local', I modified the loop as follows: 

    while ( 1 ) {
        $client_fh = $listen_socket->accept();
        next if ! defined $client_fh;

Which works.  Still trying to absorb why....

Comment: That would send your program in a 100% CPU infinite loop on a real error.

Comment: sorry for the formatting.  i mean, i'm still trying to absorb why the accept() is completing when a SIGCHLD comes in.

Comment: Sorry, the fix made no sense. Fixed.

Comment: Ah -- okay, that works *and* makes sense!  :)  I don't know how to drive the 'last' condition, but this is good.  Didn't realize that adding a SIG handler added so many side effects.  Thanks v.much.

Comment: One additional thing - in the book I'm working from, they also define a $SIG{INT} handler which sets a flag that the main while() loop checks.  This seems odd, since the loop won't check the flag until another connection comes along....  i.e. Ctrl-C has no immediate effect.  Using **next**, rather than **redo**, solves that problem -- does that seem reasonable?

Comment: @Chap: Yes, the only difference between `next` and `redo` in this case is that `next` retests the loop condition (and runs any `continue` blocks, if you have those). Of course, you could also check for it explicitly inside the `if` block, if you preferred.

Comment: Haven't seen the book, the SIGINT would interrupt `accept` just like SIGCHLD does. He's just setting a flag because one wanted to do as little as possible in signal handlers before 5.8.1; even doing that little can cause your program to segfault. 5.8.1 introduced safe-signals. You can now do as much as you want in them safely since the handler you provide Perl will only be called between statements.